# How to upload multiple files in angular8 using <jqxFileUpload>?

Tags: typescript, angular8, typescript2.0

I am the beginner of Angular8 and I want to upload multiple files using  but I can't able to store file to my local folder path

```
<jqxFileUpload #myFileUpload (onSelect)="onFileSelect($event)"  (onRemove)="onFileRemove($event)"
          [width]="300" [uploadUrl]="'upload.php'" [fileInputName]="'fileToUpload'">
</jqxFileUpload>
```

Given below  is my typescript file and I don't know how to read and store file to my local folder using typescript

```
onFileSelect(event: any):void {        

}
```

So anyone helps me to solve this issue for motivating myself to learn angular8